# Higher-Order Derivatives of $f(x(t),y(t))$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In [Link](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/14%3A_Differentiation_of_Functions_of_Several_Variables/14.5%3A_The_Chain_Rule_for_Multivariable_Functions), Eq. (14.5.2), given $z=f(x(t),y(t))$ then
$$
\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt}+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}.
$$
Is there any result on the $n$-th order derivative of $z$?

Comment: It's not pretty, which is why it is never written down. Using the formula would be $n$ times as hard as just deriving it yourself every time you have to do it (which may be twice in a life)

Comment: To give an example, $$\frac{d^2 z}{dt^2} = \left(\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y \partial x}\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} + \left(\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial y}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}$$ This is already horrendous! Not to mention, the most general chain rule would have $x$ and $y$ be functions of multiple variables, not just functions of $t$ so the formula increases in complexity